# How to add a transition or an animation when toggling hidden class off a div using tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a menu that's opened and closed by an onclick and it's controlled by a state , it looks like this

```
  <div
                  className={`${
                    isFirstMenuOpen ? "" : " hidden"
                  } flex flex-col px-2 mt-8 transition ease-in-out delay-150`}
                >
                  {firstSidebar.map((i) => {
                    return (
                      <Link href={i.path} key={i.path}>
                        <span>{i.name}</span>
                      </Link>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
```

I want when the menu is not hidden  anymore for it to open with a transition or an animation , is that doable and if  yes how would I do it with tailwind?

Comment: can't animate display none, you need to add extra classes and compose two animations that removes the element from the document flow. here is an example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cS9xx6x1Ll?file=css